# Mongoose sort documents on the basis of latitude and longitude information with text index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

I am working on search feature in which user can search for some restaurant. The scenario  is :

I am having restaurant collection in which I have multiple locations with its latitude and longitude information.
Now during search,

I have user's location information (with latitude and longitude). So I have to sort the restaurant on the basis of users locations from nearest to farthest and have to text search on the content of the fields indexed with a text index.

I am having different scenarios for search so I am using aggregation pipeline and projection for scoring of results.
Can someone suggest me that from where I can start ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use geonear query of mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps:

**Step1:**

Add location field in your schema and create 2dsphere indexing on it.

```
location: { type: [Number], index: '2dsphere' }
```

You can also create indexing dynamically:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { <location field> : "2dsphere" } )
```

**Step2**

Now create an aggregate query with $geoNear:

```
var aggregateQuery = [{
        "$geoNear": {
            "near": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [options.longitude, options.latitude]
            },
            "distanceField": 'dis',
            "distanceMultiplier": .001,
            "spherical": true,
            "query": **conditions**
        }
    }];
```

you can pass any condition in query parameter.

```
db.collectionname.aggregate(aggregateQuery).exec(function(err, result){
// use result here
})
```

**NOTE:** Remember to store longitude first in location array and then latitude.

For more details refer to this link:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/geoNear/

Hope this helps!!

**UPDATE**:

```
db.collectionname.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      $text: {$search: "text"} ,
      location: {$geoWithin: {$centerSphere: [[ longitude, latitude], points]}}
  }}])
```

Note: The geo index won't be used!

For more info refer to this link http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/

Comment: Thanks, However I can't use this method. I am using aggregation pipeline with a $textSearch. According to mongo doc, $goNear shoud be the first item in the aggregation pipeline. Same restriction is there for $textSearch. I can't drop using the $textSearch. Is there a way to use both in the aggregation pipeline?